# What’s going on with “food > feed”? Is it like “foot > feet”?

Tags: verbs, nouns

I am looking for a particular linguistic term for this process of turning nouns like food into verbs like feed. For all I know, it may be older than English, perhaps even going back all the way to OE.
English has a bunch of noun-verb pairs like these:
food, feed
blood, bleed
brood, breed
doom, deem?
What is going on there? What does it mean?

Comment: Look up **I-mutation**, **Umlaut** and **Indo-European Ablaut**.

Comment: Note that **feed** and **breed** are also nouns. I am not convinced that **brood** and **breed** are connected, nor **doom/deem**.

Comment: [Looking](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=food) at [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=feed), this goes back to Proto-Germanic, where one of these pairs of words had a palatalized ccnsonant ending the first syllable (i.e., *fodon* and *fodjan*). This palatalization eventually disappeared, but it seems to have raised the vowel before it. One wonders whether this happened with other vowels, as well.

Comment: And it seems likely that the different vowels in *foot/feet* also arose because the following palatalized consonant raised the vowel. In Proto-West Germanic, *foot* and *feet* were [fōt and fōti](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-West_Germanic/f%C5%8Dt)