# What’s going on with "hot -> heat”?

Tags: terminology, orthography, linguistics, phonology, vowels

I am looking for a particular linguistic term for this process of turning words like *hot* into words like *heat*.
English has a bunch of pairs like these:

- Hot -> heat
- Whole -> heal
- (Folk)lore -> learn
- Dole -> deal?
- Token -> teach?

What is going on there? What does it mean?

Comment: Could be [apophony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophony)

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what the pattern is? How do I transform a word from column 1 to one from column 2?

Comment: i got the hot and heat but what's the analogy between whole and heal? and the rest?

Comment: What happened here is that the two vowels were always slightly different to begin with, or rather two different versions of the same vowel. The linguistic term you are looking for there is "umlaut", and related languages like German have kept these to this day. But English had the Great Vowel Shift, which is the second term you can look up, during which every vowel shifted purely depending on what it sounded like, and not on what base vowel it was a variation of in each particular word. Hence *hot/heat* and *mouse/mice* and so on. (Which e.g. in German are still *heiß/Hitze* and *Maus/Mäuse*.)

Comment: @ThePhoton and JustTolerateMe: *lore* and *learn* come from the same root, *whole* and *heal* are essentially the same word, and likewise for *dole* and *deal*. This is a valid question and the OP deserves more credit than they are currently receiving from us. When in doubt, check etymonline.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, Your comments make a good answer.

Comment: Closely related: [Was “book” to “beek” as “foot” is to “feet”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/77866/365490)

Comment: @RegDwigнt, I didn't mean to imply it was a bad question. But I think it would be better if OP is more explicit about the pattern they're asking about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Was "book" to "beek" as "foot" is to "feet"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77848/was-book-to-beek-as-foot-is-to-feet) - (It's the same phenomenon, so your question is a duplicate.) Also see [your previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/541058/what-s-going-on-with-food-feed-is-it-like-foot-feet) which is also a duplicate.